# Error: Cannot find module '@actions/core' - when running my GitHub Action from another repo

Tags: node.js, typescript, github-actions, node-modules

I have made a GitHub Action in a private repo:

```
import * as core from '@actions/core';
import * as github from '@actions/github';

async function run() {
  try {
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      core.setFailed(error.message);
    } else {
      core.setFailed('Unknown error has occurred: ' + error);
    }
  }
}

run();
```

When I run this action from another private repo I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@actions/core'
```

I don't get this error in Visual Studio Code, only when running the Action on GitHub.

All the modules are installed, I have even built into JS file but still get the error, and my TypeScript config is correct also. Any ideas?

```
Action:
    name: 'Action'
    description: 'GitHub Action.'
    author: 'G'
    inputs: {}
    runs:
      using: 'node16'
      main: 'dist/main.js'
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["./*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Can you also update your package.json file?

Comment: Your action needs to commit the `node_modules` folder in its repo against what you're used to probably.  Alternatively use vercel/ncc or some other tool to compile your action into a single `js` file and commit that. See the tutorial here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to install the node package:

```bash
npm i @actions/core
```

Edit: do the same for `@actions/github`, it'll error too